# JLabel image is not displayed in Applet when run it in browser

Tags: java, image, embedded-resource, japplet, netbeans-8

I have written java applet in Netbeans8 to display images in `jLabel`. When run in Netbeans the images are showing up just fine. In HTML page the images won't display. Images are placed in same directory along with applet.

Here is the code relevant code:

```
Images = new String[5];
Images[0] = "Chrysanthemum.jpg";
Images[1] = "Desert.jpg";
Images[2] = "Hydrangeas.jpg";
Images[3] = "Lighthouse.jpg";
Images[4] = "Penguins.jpg";

try {
    jLabel1.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("Jellyfish.jpg")));
    ImageIndex++;
} catch (Exception ex) {
    System.out.println(ex.toString());
}
```

Please help to resolve this issue on browser.

Comment: Do you mean you use the browser to run the applet?

Answer (score 1):

In the IDE, [getResource](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String))() will return the following two forms of absolute path (get from java 1.7 API) and you get the image.

`If the name begins with a '/' ('\u002f'), then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.`

`Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form: modified_package_name/name.

Where the modified_package_name is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.' ('\u002e').`

So in the browser, it can't get the right class path for the path of package changed.

**Solution:** as Hovercraft said, you may need [Packaging and Deploying Desktop Java Applications](https://netbeans.org/kb/articles/javase-deploy.html) and add it to the same folder with the package.

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to get the images as a resource, and so they should be packaged in the jar file.

Comment: how can i do that in netbeans?

Comment: @NidaSulheri: I don't use NetBeans, but surely it has a tutorial showing how to package resources into the jar file.